# Can I extend an Oracle ADF (or any Java EE) war/ear without having access to the source?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, extending-classes

There is a packaged application created in Oracle ADF (lets generalise and say any Java EE framework) that I would like to customise/extend. I want to make changes like add a new JSF page or modify a JSF page in there and change the data which appears on the page.

I do not have the source code, just the war/ear file. Can I import this in JDeveloper for ADF (or Eclipse/NetBeans/IntelliJ in case of other EE frameworks) and create new objects extending the jar files in there without having the source code?

Comment: Did you try to unzip it?

Comment: Unzip the ear file? No. Why do I need to, I can import the ear file into the IDE.

Comment: Just give it a try!

Comment: When I open the ear file in JDeveloper, it unzips it, along with all the constituent jar/war/ear files. What exactly do you want me to unzip?

Answer (score 2):

You can run your Jdev in customisation Developer role , open your EAR file , go to your JSF , jsff and try to have customisation put on top of it. You will need to deploy this as MAR file. Similar concept also applies to Oracle's Webcenter and it's taskflow customisations. Also , for this feature Seeded customisation should be enabled in your deployment profile.

Read more here : [Customization](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/webcenter.1111/e10148/jpsdg_taskflows.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Also found this - how customisable the ADF app is depends on how the app is written in the first place. Use of MDS enables higher degree of customisability:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/ADFFD/customize.htm#ADFFD2085